# Is It Possible to Use a File Scanner Multiple Times Without Declaring Multiple Scanners?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm making a program for my improv theater that will help us pick out games we play in shows on a night without overlapping styles of any other games. I've come into a problem though. In the code below, Scanner scWU reads a .txt file that contains names of improv games, and Scanner sc is a normal System.in scanner.

I've pasted two of my methods below. **getWarmUp()** returns the string (game) after it's been deemed a doable game of a certain category (in this case, the warmup game category). **isWarmUp()** reads the warmupgames.txt file and sees if the game entered is indeed a warmup game

My question is: If the user fails to enter the name of the game (and isWarmUp returns false), how can I re-launch the method OR reset the scWU scanner at the top of the file? Would I have to declare multiple scanners? Or could I easily make the same scanner scan the file again after the user fails the first time to enter a game correctly? (NOTE: I am aware the while loop on line 25 is an infinite loop. This is where I'm hoping to address this question)

I will answer any confusion about my code

```
   public static String getWarmUp(Scanner sc, Scanner scWU)
   {
      String prompt = "What warm-up game will you choose? \n" +
                      "(NOTE: Type game as it's written on the board. Caps and symbols don't matter.)\n" +
                      "> ";

      System.out.print(prompt);
      String game = sc.nextLine();

      //This while loop is infinite. This is where I'm hoping to somehow allow the scanner to reset and
      //read again on a failed input
      while(!warmUp)
      {
         warmUp = isWarmUp(scWU, game);
         if(!warmUp)
            System.out.println("That's not a warm-up game, try again.");
      }

      return game;
   }

   public static boolean isWarmUp(Scanner scWU1, String game)
   {
      int lineNum = 0;

         while(scWU1.hasNextLine())
         {
            String line = scWU1.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(game))
               return true;
         }

      return false;
```

Comment: If you need to be able to start reading the file again, you can't pass a `Scanner` already opened on that file to your `getWarmUp` method:  you need to pass the file name as a `String` so that `getWarmUp` can open (and if necessary, close and re-open) the file for for itself.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Would I be able to use close and re-open commands in getWarmUp? Or would I need to pass file names as Strings. If the latter, could you show me a small example of how one would open a file via String?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I mean.  Presumably you're now using `getWarmUp` something like this:

```
String gamesFileName = "theGamesFile.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner games = new Scanner(gamesFileName);
getWarmUp(in, games);
```

But `getWarmUp` (or, rather, `isWarmUp`, which `getWarmUp` calls) might need to re-read the file from the beginning.  The only way it can do this is by creating a new `Scanner`.  And you'd need the filename in order to create the new `Scanner`.  So have `getWarmUp` take the filename as an argument instead of an opened `Scanner`:

```
public static String getWarmUp(Scanner sc, String gamesFn)
   {
      boolean warmUp = false;    
      while(!warmUp)
      {
          String prompt = "What warm-up game will you choose? \n" +
                          "(NOTE: Type game as it's written on the board. Caps and symbols don't matter.)\n" +
                      "> ";
          System.out.print(prompt);

          String game = sc.nextLine();

          Scanner scWU = new Scanner(gamesFn);
          warmUp = isWarmUp(scWU, game);
          scWU.close();
          if(!warmUp)
              System.out.println("That's not a warm-up game, try again.");
      }    
      return game;
   }
```

Then call it like this:

```
String gamesFileName = "theGamesFile.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
getWarmUp(in, gamesFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. I should've also mentioned I intend to use multiple .txt files for different game categories. Would I just open one scanner per .txt file then? And disassociate the names (like your example)? For instance:
`Scanner scWu = new Scanner (warmupGamesTxtFile);
 Scanner scR = new Scanner(replayGamesTxtFile);`
(Assuming the Scanner parameters are Strings with the txt files names)

Comment: I'd say try to keep it to one `Scanner` at a time if you can.  Will you ever need to read from both a warm-up game file and a replay game file at the same time?  And let's not forget about any other categories of game file that you've either already thought of or might (and remember, "might" usually turns into "definitely will")  invent in the future?  You could be up to your eyeballs in `Scanner`s if you're not careful (;->)